# PhpStorm does not recognize "<%=" tag

Tags: php, phpstorm

My php project is running with error free but PhpStorm does not recognize <%= tag as expected my PhpStorm version is: **PhpStorm 2017.2.1
Build #PS-172.3544.41, built on August 2, 2017**
The sample is below:
[image: PhpStorm screen shot]

Comment: why are you using asp like tags in the first place?

Comment: enquote the `PHP` and ignore the warnings, `name: '<?= ... ?>',`

Comment: Isn't that JSP? Why would phpstorm recognize a JSP tag?

Comment: @chiliNUT It's the ASP tag syntax. And if you think that's weird, PHP used to recognize `<script language="php">` as well…

Comment: @duskwuff whoa... I knew about the script tag but not the asp tags...gnarly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the ASP tag syntax, not the PHP syntax. Older versions of PHP used to support that syntax as an option, but [it is no longer available in PHP 7.0 or later.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) You need to stop using it, as it makes your code incompatible with current versions of PHP.

Comment: I thought it was included in php and it was the php shorthand tag, thanks.